# Make if statement true when variable matches one of the strings in a list

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I have a command that will output the following (`curl -sSL $location | grep -o "title\=\".*\"\ agent" | grep -o "\".*\"" | grep -o "[a-zA-Z0-9].*[a-zA-Z0-9]"`):

```
Films
TV Series
```

I need to make an if-statement where a variable needs to match one of those. e.g.

```
if [[ $option = Films ]] || [[ $option = "TV Series" ]]
then
    echo "True"
fi
```

But the thing is, Films and TV Series can change. The name can be different. And there is a possibility that there are more strings e.g. `Films, TV Series, Music, Radio etc. etc.` or `movie, serie, radio, music`. I need to get it so that the variable (`$option`) is able to match whatever output comes out of the command. It doesn't have to match every one of them, just one is enough e.g.

```
Output command:
Films
TV Series
Radio

$option=TV Series -> True
$option=Radio -> True

Output command:
Films

$option=Films -> True
$option=radio -> False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
if [[ "$option" == $(curl -sSL $location | grep -o "title\=\".*\"\ agent" | grep -o "\".*\"" | grep -o "$option") ]]
then
   echo true
else
   echo false
fi
```

This should also work, though I haven't tested it.

```
if ! [[ -z $(curl -sSL $location | grep -o "title\=\".*\"\ agent" | grep -o "\".*\"" | grep -o "$option") ]]
then 
   echo true
else
   echo false
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Save all genres in an array without space. You can then match your token against the array (or you can also say string with words).

```
#!/bin/bash

a=(Films TVSeries Music Radio)

option="TV Series"

[[ " ${a[*]} " \
    =~ " ${option// /} " ]] \
&& echo true || echo false
```

Comment: I would remove the space at the head and tails ends of the quoted expression. Please test with various values of `option` and convince me that I am wrong or modify your quoted expression.

Comment: No, but it should be *quotes* on the array. (or TV would match TVSeries, TVEpisoes...)

Comment: +1 It works for me after your modification :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the command is a list as you show in the question, you can save it in an array, and check the variable against it:

```sh
mapfile -t a < <(curl...)

option="TV Series"

[[ "${a[@]}" =~ "$option" ]] && \
  echo "$option → True" || \
  echo "$option → False"
```